# Convert 2d screen coordinates to 3d World Coordinates

Tags: android, c++, ios, opengl, 3d

I would like to convert 2d Screen Coordinates to 3d World Coordinates.

I put together a hack but would like a solid solution. If possible please use your equation/algorithm on the example below (if there is already a link, could you use the link to show the solution to the problem below)

My Environment is Java/C++ for Android and iOS using OpenGL 2.0

Problem to Solve

Where screen
(0,0) is top left and bottom right is screenWidth and screenHeight.

screenWidth=667; screenHeight=375;

//Camera's position,where camera is looking at, and camera direction

CamPos (0.0f,0.0f,11.0f); CamLookAt (0.0f, 0.0f, 10.5f); CamDir(0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);

//The Frustum

left =1.3f; right=1.3f; bottom=1.0f; top=1.0f; near=3.0f; far=1000.0f;

Obj

//object's position in 3d space x,y,z and scaling

objPos(1.0f, -.5f, 5.0f); objScale(.1f,.1f,0.0f);

The problem is how to convert (600,200) screen coordinates (with scaling of (.1f,.1f.0.0f))to the object's (1.0f,-.5f,5.0f) world coordinates to check if they are colliding(I am doing simple box collision, just need the 2d screen coordinates converted to world). I will put the hack that I have below but I am sure there is a better answer. Thank you in advance for any help. Please use the numbers above to show how your algorithm works.

Hack

```
//this is 0,0 in screen coordinates//-Cam_Offset =hardcoded to camera's pos
float convertedZeroY= (((mCam->right)*(Cam_Offset))); //2
float convertedZeroX= -(((Cam_Offset)+convertedZeroY));

convertedZeroY=convertedZeroY/2;
convertedZeroX=convertedZeroX/2;
//this is the length from top to bottom in game coordinates
float normX=convertedZeroX*2;
float normY=convertedZeroY*2;

//this is the screen coordinates converted to 3d world coordinates
mInput->mUserInputConverted->mPos.x=(-(((mInput->x)/mCam->mScreenW)*normX)+convertedZeroX);
mInput->mUserInputConverted->mPos.y=(-(((mInput->y)/mCam->mScreenH)*(normY))+convertedZeroY);
```

Comment: I can give you a solution I have used, but I want to be clear on the on the last part about the object's position and scale. Is the object a single point that has been scaled by 0.1 in x and y and by 0.0 (zero!) in z? There are two approaches: (1) project object into screen coords and compare, or (2) project the screen coordinate into a ray emanating from the camera into the scene (my solution uses the later).

Comment: >>Is the object a single point that has been scaled by 0.1 in x and y and by 0.0 (zero!) in z?


Yes the object has zero in the z because it is just a texture. So the width and height of the object (really texture) is .1f 

Yes I would like to see your solution for #2. Also if you could use it in the example above just to verify it works, would be awesome!

Comment: Just to add to that. I would need the ray emanating from the camera to have a point on the z axis which could be used for 2d box collision. So if the object is objPos(1.0f, -.5f, 5.0f); I would want the screen coordinates to be in a range that could be used in 2d box collision for that object. so a correct converted point  would be x .9f to1.1f and y -.4f to-.6f